# How can I globally specify the From email header for the TeamCity email notifier?

Tags: teamcity, email-headers

I've set up a gmail account to use when sending email notifications from my TeamCity installation. The emails are being sent correctly, but I want to specify the `From:` header using their .ftl files. According to [this page](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Customizing+Notifications) (under Supported Output Values), I can specify email headers. I've copied their `<global#...` block directly into a number of their template files, namely `common.ftl`, `build_successful.ftl` and it never works.

The block I added looks like this:

```
<#global headers>
    From: Some Test <myteamcitytestnotreal@gmail.com>
</#global>
```

It doesn't do anything. Neither does their sample headers. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify the From: address via the UI under `Administration > Email Notifier` -> `Send email messages from:`.

This updates the value stored in the `<TeamCity data directory>/config/_notifications/email/email-config.xml` file.

I suspect overriding the From: address at the ftl template level is not a supported approach given that the above is the [documented method](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Setting+up+Google+Mail+and+Google+Talk+as+Notification+Servers); it might make for a good feature request in TC 9.0.

Comment: I had just had an email address in that field (and it was working). I didn't know I could specify a name with it as well, as it wasn't mentioned in the doc. I find it strange that no email headers seem to be supported. Either way, what you proposed solved the problem.